# Can anyone tell how to disable caching in pdf.js?

Tags: jquery, pdf.js

I using pdf.js for displaying pdf in browser.I noticed if i scroll down a pdf (assume current page is 8)having more than one page(lets see 20).then when i refresh the page then pdf automatically open from page 8.Can we remove this thing in pdf.js so that it will open up from page 1 only.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by setting the `showPreviousViewOnLoad` to `false` with this line of code.
`PDFViewerApplication.viewerPrefs.showPreviousViewOnLoad = false`

Comment: and what about the new version?

Comment: @Criss what about it?

Answer (score 2):

Per https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/default_preferences.js#L24 , make the showPreviousViewOnLoad == `false`

Comment: Also, can you tell me if i can change the progress bar to a spinner showing the perc of loading.

Comment: where should I change this property ?